# how to hide the main menu which is not listed in a block

Tags: routes

I downloaded a theme which automatically puts my main menu in the header region.  However, when I look at my blocks you can't edit that region.

I would like to BLOCK ALL unauthenticated users from seeing the main menu.  How would i do this?  thanks!

Comment: did you check page.tpl.php may be he draw menu in it not in a region

Comment: What theme are you working with here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to lock down specific areas of the site with permissions that are not readily available on the Permissions page. I would address that issue in the following way.

I would update the theme to make the region editable and make it so that the menu was not part of the theme by default.

Next I would install the [Context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) so that I could display specific blocks, in specific regions, when specific conditions are met.

Finally I would create a Context with the settings:

**Conditions**

- "Sitewide: Always active"
- "User Roles": "Authenticated User"

**Actions**

- "Block": Main Menu

Comment: thanks, i am not a programmer, how do i make the region "editable"?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a 'Feature' of the theme.  The control for that can be found under Appearance -> Settings -> 'Theme Name' -> Find the 'Toggle Display' section and uncheck 'Main menu'.

Then you re-add the menu yourself under 'Structure' -> 'Blocks'.  Drag it to the region you want it in.  Then click 'configure' and go to 'Roles' where you can choose which roles to display the block for. (Leave anonymous user unchecked to hide this block from unauthenticated users)